# incomplete type used in nested name specifier, Why?

Tags: c++, templates, numeric-limits

The following code is a part of a fixed-length arithmetic type, i reduced it as much as i can to only contains the problem.

```
namespace MathX
{
typedef signed int    int32;
typedef unsigned int uint32;

typedef signed long long    int64;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

typedef uint32 mathx_ucomp;
typedef  int32 mathx_scomp;
typedef uint64 mathx_udcomp;
typedef  int64 mathx_sdcomp;

template<typename t>
struct sizeof_ex
{
    static const uint32 value = sizeof(t) * 8;
};

template<uint64 val>
struct is_power_of_2
{
    static const bool value = !(val & (val - 1u));
};

enum type_classes { tc_native,  tc_custom };

enum type_ids { ti_basic_int, ti_basic_float, ti_int_t, ti_uint_t, ti_float_t };

template <typename t>
struct basic_info
{
    static const bool is_signed = (t(-1) == -1);
    static const bool is_integer = (t(3.14) != 3.14);
    static const uint32 num_of_bits = sizeof_ex<t>::value;
    static const uint32 comp_bits = num_of_bits;
    static const type_classes type_class = tc_native;
    static const type_ids type_id = is_integer? ti_basic_int: ti_basic_float;
};

template<typename t>
struct global_int
{
    static const t zero;   
    static const t one;    
    static const t mone;   
    static const t minval; 
    static const t maxval; 

    static const uint32 full_t = is_power_of_2<basic_info<t>::num_of_bits>::value? basic_info<t>::num_of_bits: 0u;
    static const uint32 used_t = full_t - int32(basic_info<t>::type_id == ti_int_t);
    static const bool   sign_t = (full_t != used_t);
    static const uint32 half_t = full_t >> 1u;
    static const uint32 comp_b = is_power_of_2<basic_info<t>::comp_bits>::value? basic_info<t>::comp_bits: 0;
    static const uint32 comp_d = comp_b << 1u;
    static const uint32 comp_c = full_t / comp_b;
};

template<typename t> const t global_int<t>::zero = t(0u);
template<typename t> const t global_int<t>::one  = t(1u);
template<typename t> const t global_int<t>::mone = t(-1);
template<typename t> const t global_int<t>::minval = t(global_int<t>::sign_t? (typename t::ucomp)1 << (global_int<t>::comp_b - 1): 0, 0);
template<typename t> const t global_int<t>::maxval = t(global_int<t>::sign_t? (typename t::ucomp)~0 >> 1: (typename t::ucomp)~0, (typename t::ucomp)~0);

template <uint32 bit_count, typename ut, typename st, typename udt, typename sdt> struct int_t;

template <uint32 bit_count, typename ut, typename st, typename udt, typename sdt>
struct basic_info< int_t<bit_count, ut, st, udt, sdt> >
{
    static const bool is_signed = true;
    static const bool is_integer = true;
    static const uint32 num_of_bits = bit_count;
    static const uint32 comp_bits = sizeof_ex<ut>::value;
    static const type_classes type_class = tc_custom;
    static const type_ids type_id = ti_int_t;
};

template <typename t>
inline void mathx_int_setn(t* me)
{
    for (uint32 i=0; i < global_int<t>::comp_c; ++i) me->comp[i] = (typename t::ucomp)-1;
}


template <typename t>
inline void mathx_int_setz(t* me)
{
    for (uint32 i=0; i < global_int<t>::comp_c; ++i) me->comp[i] = 0;
}

template <typename t, typename u>
inline void mathx_int_iTt(t* me, const u& value)
{
    if (sizeof(t) > sizeof(u))
    {
        if (basic_info<u>::is_signed && ((basic_info<u>::type_id != ti_basic_int && value < global_int<u>::zero) || value < 0))
            mathx_int_setn<t>(me);
        else
            mathx_int_setz<t>(me);

        *(u*)me->comp = value;

        return;
    }

    *me = *(t*)&value;
}

template <typename t>
inline void mathx_int_init(t* me, typename t::ucomp hi, typename t::ucomp rest)
{
    typedef global_int<t> gint;
    for (uint32 i=0; i<gint::comp_c-1; ++i) me->comp[i] = rest;
    me->comp[gint::comp_c-1]=hi;
}

template <uint32 bit_count, typename ut, typename st, typename udt, typename sdt>
struct int_t
{
    typedef ut  ucomp;
    typedef st  scomp;
    typedef udt udcomp;
    typedef sdt sdcomp;

    typedef int_t<bit_count, ut, st, udt, sdt> t;
    typedef global_int<t> gint;

    ut comp[gint::comp_c];

    int_t() {}

    int_t(ut hi, ut rest) { mathx_int_init<t>(this, hi, rest); }

    template<typename u>
    int_t(const u& value)
    {
        if (basic_info<u>::is_integer)
            mathx_int_iTt<t, u>(this, value);
    }
};

typedef int_t<128, mathx_ucomp, mathx_scomp, mathx_udcomp, mathx_sdcomp > int128;

}
```

with previous code when compiling the next line, it compiles with no problem:

```
int main()
{
   MahtX::int128 q = 1024;
}
```

now i want to add support to `numeric_limits` class so i added the following code (this is a part of the class):

```
#include <limits>
namespace std
{
    using namespace ::MathX;

    template < uint32 bit_count, typename ut, typename st, typename udt, typename sdt>
    class numeric_limits< int_t< bit_count, ut, st, udt, sdt > >
    {
    public:
        typedef int_t< bit_count, ut, st, udt, sdt > t;
        typedef global_int<t> gint;

        static const bool is_specialized = true;
        static t min() throw() { return gint::minval; }
        static t max() throw()  { return gint::maxval; }
        static const int32 digits = gint::used_t;
        static const int32 digits10 = int32(digits * 0.301f);
        static const bool is_signed = true;
        static const bool is_integer = true;
        static const bool is_exact = true;
        static const int32 radix = 2;
    };
}
```

when compiling the following code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned b = std::numeric_limits< MathX::int128 >::digits10;
}
```

the gcc compiler produce the following error:
`error: incomplete type 'MathX::int_t<128u, unsigned int, int, long long unsigned int, long long int>::gint' used in nested name specifier`.

the VC++ compiler produce the following error: `error C2039: 'comp_c' : is not a member of 'MathX::global_int<t>'`.

when i delete the declaration of variables with type `t` from type `global_int` along with they definition the code compiles with no problem, but i those lines must remains and neither i can fix this problem nor finding out why it's happens.

Comment: 1) You are not allowed to add anything to the `std`-namespace. 2) The template you declare there has 5 arguments, but you are instantiate `numeric_limits` with one argument in your program, which will call the default_implementation, which will break for your type.

Comment: Technically, you should use `CHAR_BIT` instead of 8.

Comment: @bjorn-pollex: i cannot add numeric_limits to MathX namespace becuase it is not belong to it, and the int128 is a typedef, you can find its defination at the end of MathX namespace.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: this is a preprocessed version of the code.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: You are allowed to _specialize_ objects in the `std` namespace however.  What he does is allowed, except for the `using namespace ::MathX;` _inside_ of `namespace std`.  The rest is all legal.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: Also, he specializes numeric_limits with one template argument, which itself has 5 template arguments.  He's passing it `MathX::int128` which matches that argument list.  His code there should be valid.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks for the explanation. I was not sure whether this syntax was a specialization, I have never seen anything like it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: I admit, it _is_ odd, but that's how you do template specialization on a template type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the *full* MSVC10 compiler error message:

```
unsigned b = std::numeric_limits< MathX::int128 >::digits10;
```

requires instantiation of:

```
template < uint32 bit_count, typename ut, typename st, typename udt, typename sdt>
class numeric_limits< int_t< bit_count, ut, st, udt, sdt > >
{
public:
    static const int32 digits = gint::used_t;
    static const int32 digits10 = int32(digits * 0.301f);
}
```

which requires instantiation of:

```
template<typename t>
struct global_int
{
    static const uint32 full_t = is_power_of_2<basic_info<t>::num_of_bits>::value? basic_info<t>::num_of_bits: 0u;
    static const uint32 used_t = full_t - int32(basic_info<t>::type_id == ti_int_t);
}
```

which requires instantiation of:

```
template <uint32 bit_count, typename ut, typename st, typename udt, typename sdt>
struct int_t
{
    typedef global_int<t> gint;
    ut comp[gint::comp_c];
}
```

which requires instantiation of:

```
template<typename t>
struct global_int
{
    static const uint32 full_t = is_power_of_2<basic_info<t>::num_of_bits>::value? basic_info<t>::num_of_bits: 0u;
    static const uint32 comp_b = is_power_of_2<basic_info<t>::comp_bits>::value? basic_info<t>::comp_bits: 0;
    static const uint32 comp_c = full_t / comp_b;
}
```

So, `global_int<int_t>` can't be instantiated until `int_t` is instantiated, and `int_t` can't be instantiated until `global_int<int_t>` is instantiated.  This circular dependency causes it to try anyway without loading the innermost `global_int<int_t>`, causing an incomplete type error.

The solution is (obviously) to make `int_t` not depend on `global_int<int_t>`.

Also, avoid `using <namespace>` in headers wherever possible, and **do not do it inside of the std namespace ever**.  That's illegal.

Comment: Also: posting the _full_ error message would have made this easier.  Always post the full error message.

Comment: I'm using Visual C++ 2008 and what i post is the full message appeared.

Comment: That's the full message that appears in the error window yes.  Go to view->Output. Highlight the error you want in the error window, and switch to the output window to see the full message.  The error window  only shows the first line.  The output window showed me some 100 lines detailing the problem.